# Git - Create remote depository on local network drive

Tags: git, network-drive

I have a git remote repository (bare, and empty for now) on my local network that can be accessed from my computer that way :

```
//NetworkDrive/Git_Repositories/MyProjectRemote.git/
```

I also have a local C# project on my computer, that I want to push to this repository. I tried to add an origin to this uri

```
git add origin //{above uri}/
```

but when I try to push, it tells me an error about sha1 parsing. That's where the internet stopped to give me useful informations.

What did I forget? Add a user for git on the drive, and give it read/write rights? If so, I guess I should do it through powershell, shouldn't I?

I'm so upset because setting up a repo on my raspberry pi a few months (through ssh) looked much more harder, but it was easier to be done...

Comment: That is not an URI.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message you get.

Comment: @das-g I'll do that as soon as I get home